# Notifications for volume changed using terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

When I change the volume using my laptop's dedicated volume-control buttons, a pretty notification is displayed on the top right.

I have recently started using my laptop with a dock. My external keyboard does not have dedicated volume buttons. I have mapped the scroll-lock/pause-break to "amixer -D pulse sset Master playback 5%-/+". Doing so does indeed change the volume, but now the volume-change notification does not display. How do I make the notification appear when I change the volume using shortcuts on my external keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [xdotool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdotool)
package, and try using the following commands instead:

```
xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume
```

and

```
xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Ta mate! Also, is there any way to register repeated keystrokes if I keep the key pressed?

Comment: @smalltimer hmm. I'm going to say no to that, but you can always ask a new question. Either here or on [ubuntu.se] - they're more into scripting. Don't say you are using elementary OS, though. Post the link here when you ask :)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks anyway. Will post link if/when I find the answer. Cheerio now