# xdotool keypress and key release

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I just mapped my XF86AudioLowerVolume and XF86AudioRaiseVolume keys using xdotool as discussed in [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/notifications-for-volume-changed-using-terminal/3162#3162) thread. To raise/lower the volume by twice the amount, I have to press the corresponding key twice. I would like the volume to keep increasing/decreasing while the appropriate key is pressed and to stop changing when it is released.

Is it possible to do this with just one command rather than a script? Perhaps using a clever xdotool command?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you cannot because even if `xdotool` can generate events like key (a given keystroke), key up (a given key released) and key down (a given key pressed), you cannot map them with Keyboard Shortcuts because the latter handles only simple keystroke events.

You would need a tool that can map the press/release events as well.